# NoClassDefFoundError for AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder on runtime

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am getting following exception and not able to figure out what exactly is going wrong?

```
START RequestId: 6e561b8c-2fd0-11e8-8bd0-edfc4c9a75aa Version: $LATEST
com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder: **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder**
    at com.tarkshala.dynamodb.StudentDAOImpl.create(StudentDAOImpl.java:12)
    at com.tarkshala.lambda.StudentController.handleRequest(StudentController.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

My pom.xml looks like below:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.301</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Even my IDE is resolving class defination then why it is creating problem on runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error message it looks like you are trying to query DynamoDb from a Lambda function implemented in Java.

When using Java based AWS Lambda functions your function code must contain all dependencies. You can’t rely on Lambda to resolve your dependencies from a pom.xml, the way a local system using Maven would.

The most common way is to generate a single JAR (commonly called a “fat JAR”) containing your code and all dependencies required by your code (typically everything in the classpath that would be required to execute your code).

Once you get the dependencies deployed to Lambda along with your code, things should start working as you expect.

See: more info about how to [generate a fat JAR using a Maven plugin](https://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/java/how-to-create-a-fat-jar-using-maven.html)

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I added the shade plugin in my pom and am running mvn package, but still getting the same error. @KuldeepYadav how did you get it working?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/kuldeepiitg/nAqBRK
Hope this will help you.

Comment: @KuldeepYadav I have no idea what I am suppose to infer from the snippet you shared above.